# Polymorphism/virtuals in static objects

Tags: c++, inheritance

Consider the below outlined (slightly constructed) polymorphism. I boiled it down to the essence from a larger plugin infrastructure.

The basic idea is that every plugin inherits from `Transporter` and then additionally from the interfaces it wishes to provide. This in fact is aligned with Qt's idea of plugins where the plugin itself is an instance of `QObject` that additionally inherits the interfaces. The interface classes themselves are purely abstract classes.

One now might want to dump information about a plugin, like which of the interfaces it implements. For this some bits of meta information are collected in a static const array about every single interface (like the interface's descriptive title):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Base
struct Transporter {
    virtual ~Transporter() { }
};

// Interfaces
struct ICar {};
struct ITrain {};
struct IPlane {};

// Meta data
struct MetaInfoBase {
    const char *m_title;
    MetaInfoBase(const char *title):
        m_title(title) { }

    virtual bool hasInterface(Transporter *) { return false; }
};

template<typename T>
struct MetaInfo: public MetaInfoBase {
    MetaInfo(const char *title): MetaInfoBase(title) { }

    bool hasInterface(Transporter *t) { return dynamic_cast<T *>(t); }
};

MetaInfoBase infos[3] = {
    MetaInfo<ICar>("Car"),
    MetaInfo<ITrain>("Train"),
    MetaInfo<IPlane>("Plane")
};


class SomeTransporter:
    public Transporter,
    public ITrain {

};

int main() {
    Transporter *theTransporter = new SomeTransporter;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (infos[i].hasInterface(theTransporter)) // <--- ???
            cout << "the transporter implements " << infos[i].m_title << endl;
    }
}
```

How could one implement the `hasInterface` method in question? Obviously, the way it has been implemented in the above code does not work because the virtual functions are not resolved when calling them without the `->` operator.

This has been implemented before using a huge `switch` that contained a `dynamic_cast` for every interface. But I like the idea to have all the meta data collected at one point. Also, if possible, the interface classes should remain pure abstract, so it is not desirable to have the meta data there.

The above code in fact would work if the array contained heap-allocated objects like this:

```
MetaInfoBase *infos[3] = {
    new MetaInfo<ICar>("Car"),
    new MetaInfo<ITrain>("Train"),
    new MetaInfo<IPlane>("Plane")
};
```

But strictly speaking this would introduce a memory leak and I am not sure if I like to have static objects on the heap.

Comment: _"How could one implement the hasInterface method in question?"_ With a `dynamic_cast<>` maybe?

Comment: You did notice that it actually is implemented using `dynamic_cast` and that the very problem lies elsewhere?

Comment: Why is this a memory leak? You have constant memory usage, independent of user input and execution time, haven't you?

Comment: I'm unsure how or when to free the allocated objects. On the other hand, I totally see your point and it's probably not even necessary to free it manually. It's freed upon program termination anyway.

Comment: @Kamajii _"I'm unsure how or when to free the allocated objects."_ What about using `std::unique_ptr<>` instead of raw pointers? Or at least `std::shared_ptr<>` if there are multiple references.

Comment: I like using atexit()b